# Remove php extenstion from url bar

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

My website is `https://www.artisangateway.com` it opens with
`https://www.artisangateway.com/ArtisanGateway.php`.

I would very much like to understand how to use mod_rewrite to eliminate the `ArtisanGateway.php` from the url bar.

Comment: You don't need mod-rewrite, just name the file `index.php` instead of `ArtisanGateway.php`.

Comment: i used to do this https://github.com/medilies/noob-mvc/blob/main/web/public/.htaccess

Comment: You currently have a 302 external redirect from the root to `/ArtisanGateway.php`. You need to change this or know where/how it is configured before considering the removal of the `.php` extension (or `/ArtisanGateway.php` altogether). "Remove php extenstion from url bar" / "eliminate the `ArtisanGateway.php` from the url bar" - which is it?